# Select 5 random list items as array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, random

I'd like to have a button that selects 5 list items at random from an unsorted HTML list in jQuery. I want to also make sure that the function first will make sure that if there are 5 or less list items, it will simply select all the list items available. Also, I want to make sure that the random 5 has no duplicates in its array. Also, let's say there's 28 list items, I'd like it to select 5 at random that have not yet been selected, since you can click the button multiple times. So basically I'd like to to select 5 at random until the entire list has been selected. Here is what I have so far.

```
<ul id="masterlist">
    <li><a href="http://www.example1.com" target="_blank">Example 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example2.com" target="_blank">Example 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example3.com" target="_blank">Example 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example4.com" target="_blank">Example 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example5.com" target="_blank">Example 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example6.com" target="_blank">Example 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example7.com" target="_blank">Example 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example8.com" target="_blank">Example 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.example9.com" target="_blank">Example 9</a></li>
</ul>
<button id="openfiverandom">Open 5 Random</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#openfiverandom').bind('click', function(event) {
            var links = $('#masterlist li a');
            var len = links.length;
            if (len <= 5) {
                $('#masterlist li a').each( function() { this.click(); })
            }
            else {
                while(links.length > 5) {
                    links.eq(parseInt(len * Math.random())).hide();
                }
                links.each( function() { this.click(); })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't work and it doesn't check for duplicates either. I'm hoping to find a better solution here on stackoverflow. Also keep in mind the links have target="_blank" which means they will still all open, it won't stop at the first one since it doesn't forward the current page. I was also thinking that it might be easier to simply randomize the master list array, and then slice the first five. Not sure how to do that, though.

Comment: be aware that triggering click won't open link

Comment: It does, actually, @charlietfl. It works in another function I have.

Comment: not cross browser it won't. Security feature so people don't have all sorts of stuff opening at random ( at least it didn't used to work)

Comment: that is true. In Chrome it opens one link in a new tab and the rest each in its own window. In Firefox it opens all new tabs (which is what I want)

Comment: try in IE then...used to not be able to do it cross browser...maybe browser vendors have changed things...am surprised. Safer to use `window.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my primary problem I was having with this feature. So far it only works as desired in Firefox. It doesn't yet have *all* the bells and whistles on it but it does open 5 random links. The best method ended up being to shuffle the list then slicing it down to the first 5 like I mentioned in my initial post. Let me know if you guys have any questions.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            var items = $(this).children().clone(true);
            return (items.length) ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items)) : this;
        });
    }

    $.shuffle = function(arr) {
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    }

    $('#openfiverandom').bind('click', function (event) {
        var links = $.shuffle($('#masterlist li a')).slice(0, 5);
        links.each(function () { this.click(); });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#openfiverandom').bind('click', function (event) {
        var links = $('#masterlist li a'),
            len = links.length,
            random, i, $a;
        if (len <= 5) {
            links.click();
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                random = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
                $a = links.eq(random).click();
                links = links.not($a)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QY445)

*Note: Triggering a manual click event will not open a new window because the native click handler may not be invoked by the browser*

Answer (score 1):

You can manually build a filtered jQuery instance as below:

```
$('#openfiverandom').bind('click', function (event) {
    var links = $('#masterlist li a').show();
    var len = links.length;

    var $filtered = $(); //create a new jQuery object we're going to fill
    var $random;
    while ($filtered.length < 5 || $filtered.length !== links.length) {
        $random = links.eq(Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        if(!$filtered.contains($random)) $filtered.push($random); //grab some random element from links
    }
    $filtered.click();
});
```

Edit, thought about it some more on the way home and thought of a nicer solution (which isnt truly random) (you can simplify slightly more if desired):

```
 $('#openfiverandom').bind('click', function (event) {
    var links = $('#masterlist li a').show();

    var added = 0;
    var $filtered = links.filter(function() {
        if(added >= 5) return false;
        return (links.length - added < 5 || Math.round(Math.random())) && ++added; //++added is going to be truthy
    });
    $filtered.click();
});
```